# Entropy formula in J language

Tags: fork, hook, entropy, j

I'm playing a bit with the J programming language, and I've tried to create a verb for computing entropy from a list of probabilities (outcomes of an event, formula would be like this in python/pesudocode: `-sum([p*log(p,2) for p in ps])`).

The version I've tried using composition (`@:`) works, but the one based on *hook* & *fork* seems to be doing something else, and I care about **why it's doing** what it does. I'm trying to grok working with *hook* and *fork*, and this case really proves my intuitions are wrong.

Here is the code:

```
   probs =: 0.75 0.25    NB. probabilties
   entropy =: +/ @: (- * 2&^.)
   entropyWrong =: +/ (- * 2&^.)
   entropy probs         NB. this is correct
0.811278
   entropyWrong probs    NB. this is wrong!
 1.06128 1.25
0.561278 0.75
   NB. shouldn't the following be the same as above (wrong)?
   +/ (- * 2&^.) probs
0.811278
```

The point of my question isn't "how to compute entropy of probabilities in JS", but "why does the `entropyWrong` above does what it does and why it's not the same as "it's content" which does the right thing apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entropyWrong definition is a hook that you are using monadically.

```
entropyWrong =: +/ (- * 2&^.)
```

If a monadic hook is represented as `(u v) y` then in your case `+/` is u and `(- * 2&^.)` is v; v is a fork. y of course is probs, the noun argument.

J defines the actions of a monadic hook as equivalent to `y u v y` so that u becomes dyadic with y as its left argument and v y as its right argument. This is consistent with J's right to left order of execution.

By the way, forks are defined `(f g h) y` where f, g and h are verbs and the result is `(f y) g h y`. Each verb can be described as a tine of the fork and the middle tine g is dyadic while f and h are monadic when a fork if applied monadically.

`entropy =: +/ @: (- * 2&^.)` is doing something different. Entropy is in form `u @: v` and is taking the results of the fork v and applying them monadically to the verb u

If you would like to get rid of the use of `@:` in entropy, you can do that by using the verb `[:` . When used as the left tine of a fork `[:` returns no result and this creates a monadic centre tine instead of a dyadic one.

```
   entropy2=: [: +/ (- * 2&^.) NB. with three verbs this is now a fork
   probs =: 0.75 0.25
   entropy2 probs
0.811278
```

Comment: thanks! great and unambiguous explanation. but now I'm left with the question: what does "dyadic `+/`" do? I thought the verb resulting from applying the '/' adverb to a dyadic verb is automatically monadic (makes no sense otherwise to me as I think of it like `foldl +` in languages like ML/Haskell). I don't seem to find documentation for it, and from the results of expressions like `1 2 +/ 100 200` I can't deduce the logic for it...

Comment: No problem.  The dyadic form of +/ is called Table and can best be explained in the vocabulary section of the J Dictionary. http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d420.htm   Essentially, it takes each item of the left argument (items may or may not be atoms) and applies them to the items of the right argument. J for C programmers has a good section on these sort of things in the discussion of verb rank  http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/loopless_code_i_verbs_have_r.htm